# Any way to change message format in MQ Console (IBM MQ docker)?

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using the [IBM MQ docker image](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container), and I can't seem to change the message format. Is there any way to do so? After I click `Create +`, I see a "Format" field, but it appears to be uneditable. Is there a way to change this?

[image: Some message creation options]

Comment: I think the questions should be "Any way to change the message format from MQ Console or even from REST API".

Comment: Sound like the screen only provides very limited (only one) type of message format (i.e. string).  You should try a tool like [MQ Visual Edit](https://capitalware.com/mqve_overview.html) to create/update/delete messages in a queue.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MQ Console uses the IBM MQ REST API to send messages and is meant more for simple "hello world" testing purposes.

According to the IBM MQ 9.2 Knowledge center page [IBM MQ>Reference>Developing applications reference>Messaging REST API reference>REST API resources>/messaging/qmgr/{qmgrName}/queue/{queueName}/message>POST](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q130750_.htm):

> Messages are sent as MQSTR formatted messages, and are put using the current user context.
>
> ...
>
> **Request body format**
> The request body must be text and use UTF-8 encoding. No specific text structure is required. An MQSTR formatted message containing the request body text is created and put to the specified queue.

Answer (score 3):

The IBM MQ v9.2.0 REST API supports plain text format (UTF-8 encoded String) messages.

There is Swagger documentation for the REST messaging API available via the IBM MQ Console as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q128290_.htm)

More information on MQ REST Messaging can be found in the IBM MQ Knowledge Centre [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q130940_.htm%C2%A0%3C%20There%20is%20also%20a%20tutorial%20here%20%3E%C2%A0ibm.biz/mq-rest) and there is a simple REST tutorial available [here](https://ibm.biz/mq-rest).

It looks like you are connected to the IBM MQ console running in your docker container. If you take a look at your `docker run` command, you should see that port `1414` has been allocated for messaging and port `9443` allocated to the console.

As [@JoshMc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7264620/joshmc) says, the 'create message' feature of the console is designed to put a simple message onto a queue using input from the user as a payload. Only the MQSTR message type is supported and there is no option to upload message data from a file.

If you would like to use a GUI to put and get messages using different message types, then take a look at the rfhutil tool available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-rfhutil)

You can also use the MQ APIs to work with different payload types. This [GitHub Repo](https://ibm.biz/mq-dev-patterns) provides samples for a range of languages as a starting point.

This [tutorial](https://ibm.biz/mq-simple-jms) provides a worked example for a simple JMS application using Strings. It would be possible to change the `JmsPutGet.java` application to send and receive a different message type e.g., bytes messages. This is achieved by changing the JMS message type from `javax.jms.TextMessage` to `javax.jms.BytesMessage` as follows:

Add the following imports

```
import javax.jms.BytesMessage;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
```

Change the producer to work with bytes messages

```
BytesMessage bytesMessage = context.createBytesMessage();

String payload = "Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber;
byte[] bytesPayload = payload.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
bytesMessage.writeBytes(bytesPayload);
```

And change the consumer to work with bytes messages

```
consumer = context.createConsumer(destination);
byte[] receivedBytesMessage = consumer.receiveBody(byte[].class, 15000); // in ms or 15 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I'll look into those resources.

Comment: Nice answer Rich, good to see another IBMer providing answers here.